# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished after cloning a GitHub project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recently cloned my project on GitHub after changing machine, I ran bundle install and started the local server, the got this message:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

After Googling I manually created a database.yml file and entered this information:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

and ran rake db:create and rake db:migrate but I still get the error, can anyone suggest anything?

BTW, here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fchange', '0.0.5'
  gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  gem 'win32console', '1.3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your database migrations:

```
# from command line
rake db:migrate
```

Then, if there's a `db/seeds.db` file, you can use it to seed your database:

```
rake db:seed
```